# view()->share() is not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, view

i have this error

> Undefined variable: theloai (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\LaravelDemo\resources\views\layout\menu.blade.php)

this is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\TheLoai;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    //
    function __contruct()
    {
        $theloai = TheLoai::all();
        view()->share('theloai', $theloai);
    }

    function trangchu()
    {
        return view('pages.trangchu');
    }

    function lienhe()
    {
        return view('pages.lienhe');
    }
}
```

this is my menu i have this error

> Undefined variable: theloai (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\LaravelDemo\resources\views\layout\menu.blade.php)

```
<div class="col-md-3 ">
    <ul class="list-group" id="menu">
        <li href="#" class="list-group-item menu1 active">
            Menu
        </li>

        @foreach($theloai as $tl)
            @if(count($tl->loaitin) > 0)
                <li href="#" class="list-group-item menu1">
                    {{ $tl->Ten }}
                </li>

                <ul>
                    @foreach($tl->loaitin as $lt)
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <a href="#">{{ $lt->Ten }}</a>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: haev you tried ussing the Facede? `View::share('key', 'value');` ?

Comment: `function __contruct()` is working ok with that typo?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers)

Comment: i have try `View::share('key', 'value');` cant work

Comment: Correct the typo in the constructor , it is `__construct()` . and try again

Answer (score 0):

try using  wrap() instead share() Please refer new methods here https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Container/Container.html

Comment: i cant open it , it say not found

Answer (score 0):

i have try to put the 
$theloai = TheLoai::all();
        view()->share('theloai', $theloai); to App/Providers/AppServiceProvider and it work guys